# Display values of one column when using conditionals based on two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

| Country | Total Cases | Total Deaths | Recovered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| China | 741 | 147 | 987 |
| Sweden | 381 | 021 | 242 |
| Italy | 219 | 100 | 088 |

I am using Pandas and I'm trying to think of a function which enumerates the `Country` where there are current cases, i.e. where `Total Cases` minus `Total Deaths` exceeds `Recovered`. I'm really new at this - just drawing a blank.

I tried this:

```
def active_countries(data):
    df['TC-TD'] = df['Total Cases'] - df['Total Deaths']
    if df['TC-TD'] > df['Recovered']==True
        print('Country')
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [297], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 active_countries(latest)

Input In [295], in active_countries(data)
      1 def active_countries(data):
      2     df['TC-TD'] = df['Total Cases'] - df['Total Deaths']
----> 3     if df['TC-TD'] > df['Recovered']==True:
      4         print('Country')

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )
```

Comment: Share what you have tried for..so that we can help you

Comment: Oh gosh, its embarrassing okay

Comment: Sorry first post - what do I mark as correct if there are multiple correct answers?

Comment: you can vote for all correct answers and whatever best suit for your question mark that as best answer :)

Comment: Hi. A new user needs a reputation of 15 or higher to [up-vote answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220500/how-does-one-get-enough-reputation-to-upvote-or-answer-in-stackoverflow). You will get a few added reputation points if you [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the posted code with this:

```
def active_countries(data):
    df['TC-TD'] = df['Total Cases'] - df['Total Deaths']
    rows = df[df['TC-TD'] > df['Recovered']]
    countries = list(rows["Country"])
    print(countries)
    return countries
```

**Output:**

```
['Sweden', 'Italy']
```

Alternatively, the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function is a powerful way to filter a data frame with complex conditional logic.

```pythonreformar
import pandas as pd

data = {"Country": ["China", "Sweden", "Italy"],
        "Total_Cases": [741, 381, 219],
        "Total_Deaths": [147, 21, 100],
        "Recovered": [987, 242, 88]}
                        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df) 
rows = df.query('(Total_Cases - Total_Deaths) > Recovered')
#print(rows)
# if just want the country names
print(list(rows["Country"]))
```

**Output:**

Raw list:

```
  Country  Total_Cases  Total_Deaths  Recovered
0   China          741           147        987
1  Sweden          381            21        242
2   Italy          219           100         88
```

Results from query:

```
['Sweden', 'Italy']
```

If the original data has whitespace in the column names, it's simpler dealing with names with no spaces. Do this to rename the column names.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Total Cases': 'Total_Cases', 'Total Deaths': 'Total_Deaths'})
```

Comment: Is there a way to return just the `Country` column or enumerate the `['Sweden', 'Italy']` list?

Comment: @InfrequentMe Assign `list(rows["Country"])` to a variable and return that variable. Then you can iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

def check(dframe):
    for index, row in dframe.iterrows():
        if (row['Total Cases']-row['Total Deaths'] > row['Recovered']):
            print(row['Country'])


            
check(df)
```

With `test.csv`:

```
Country,Total Cases,Total Deaths,Recovered
China,741,147,987
Sweden,381,021,242
Italy,219,100,088
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(df[df["Total Cases"]-df["Total Deaths"]>df["Recovered"]])
```

output:

```
  Country  Total Cases  Total Deaths  Recovered
1  sweden          381            21        242
2   italy          219           100         88
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the [] notation. You can read the bracket notation as a conditional on the underlying data which returns a vector of bools. If an entry in this vector is true, it is returned, false it is not.

In this example we take the df['Total Cases'] series and subtract df['Total Deaths'] from it, and compare the resulting series against the df['Recovered']. This creates a bool vector (or Series), that we use the bracket notation with. We then select just the 'Country' column from that.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

input = '''
"Country","Total Cases","Total Deaths","Recovered"
"China",741,147,987
"Sweden",381,21,242
"Italy", 219,   100, 88
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input))

print(df[df['Total Cases'] - df['Total Deaths'] > df['Recovered']]['Country'])
```

Ouput:

```
1    Sweden
2     Italy
Name: Country, dtype: object
```